# Internal FLOPPY drive using Lubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, mount, lubuntu, udisks, floppy

## QUESTION SUSPENDED, DON'T BOTHER, THE DRIVE IS PROBABLY FAULTY, I CAN'T HAVE IT CHECKED UNTIL LATER, THANK YOU ALL!

The situation has radically changed so this is a completely new version of my question.

My computer has Intel Celeron CPU 2.53 GHz.

cdrom  Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Bionic Beaver release amd64 (20180725)

I turned the plug from the computer to the internal floppy drive and the drive came alive. The light is now on permanently. When I enter a floppy, I can hear it turning.

In booting, I went to the Setup Menu and enabled Floppy A 1.44 Mb 3 1/2"

[BIOS menu](http://correctlubricant.co.za//BIOS_menu.jpg)

[next screen](http://correctlubricant.co.za/Standard.jpg) better picture needed?

[BIOS screen](http://correctlubricant.co.za/BIOS.jpg)

nautilus now sees the drive but the drive does not open there. Properties do not include any useful information, it's all "unknown", but my other memories in the computer, that work well, show the same "unknown" Properties.

Accessories-Disks sees Floppy Drive. The only info given there is /dev/fd0
In Volumes it says No media if if the floppy turns in the drive.

command

gedit /dev/fd0

cannot open the file. File dev/fd0 is a block device, 0 bytes. I am not allowed to change permissions to allow execute.

command

gedit dev/fd0

opens a blank file fd0

File Manager, PCManFM 1.2.5, does not see the drive.

The following correction has been previously done (changed 3 times 1 to 0) in

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo gedit /etc/modules


# PC floppy drives
KERNEL=="fd*", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY}="0"

# USB floppy drives
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08", ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="04", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY}="0"

# ATA Zip drives
ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="*IOMEGA*", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="*ZIP*", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY_ZIP}="0"
```

Now I tried some commands:

```
vavruch@Study:~$ mount -tvfat /dev/fd0 /mnt
mount: only root can use "--types" option
```

and

```
vavruch@Study:~$ fdmount
fdmount (): Must run with EUID=root
```

I don't understand any of  that. Similar command

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo mount /dev/fd0 /floppy -t vfat
mount: /floppy: mount point does not exist.
```

Command

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo udisks --mount /dev/fd0
sudo: udisks: command not found
```

the same with

```
vavruch@Study:~$ udisks --mount /dev/fd0
```

then I tried

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo adduser $USER floppy
The user `vavruch' is already a member of `floppy'.
```

then I tried

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo lsmod | grep floppy
```

and

```
vavruch@Study:~$ lsmod | grep -i floppy
```

both return

```
floppy                 77824  0
```

then I tried

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo modprobe floppy
```

does nothing, same with

```
vavruch@Study:~$ modprobe floppy
```

and with

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo chmod 777 /media/floppy
```

and with

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo floppycontrol
```

then I tried

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo mkdir /media/floppy
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/floppy’: File exists
```

Yes, it exists in File Manager but does not show the disk.

```
vavruch@Study:~$ su -c mdir a:
No passwd entry for user 'a:'
```

and

```
vavruch@Study:~$ uname -a
Linux Study 4.15.0-91-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 11:09:48 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As you see, I do not know what I am doing.

Anything else I could try?

My knowledge is rudimentary, if you are kind enough to answer, please don't expect any knowledge E.g. if I must type sudo, tell  – Petr yesterday    Deleteme that, give me the full command.

Additional edit. I tried MANY floppies with the following command:

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo fdmount -l
NAME   TYPE  STATUS
 fd0  1440K  not mounted
```

SUMMARY: File Manager does not see my floppies. I have tried many floppies, some from 2007, nothing works.

If there is no solution, the drive might be faulty. I can't have it checked while I am not allowed to leave home.

Tried later:

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo mount /dev/fd0 /mnt
mount: /mnt: /dev/fd0 is not a valid block device.
```

this while the floppy is turning in the drive. Turns as soon as inserted.

```
vavruch@Study:~$ sudo ls /mnt
```

and

```
vavruch@Study:~$ ls /mnt
```

do not do anything with the floppy is turning in the drive.

```
vavruch@Study:~$ /media/vavruch/disk:/dev/fd0
bash: /media/vavruch/disk:/dev/fd0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to 3.5" rigidly cased floppies.

Comment: Yes, sorry to use a term that is not common, 3.5" rigidly cased floppies!

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could tidy up your questions, you didn't include line breaks for your pastes so it's easier for you to re-do than me edit it (I would have to work out where line breaks are then add {}).  What architecture are you using? as I booted a Lubuntu 18.04.4 qa-test install & I mounted a floppy *that appears to have WP files from 1993-1994 on*.  On a amd64 box the 'floppy' module wasn't loaded by default so it wouldn't have worked as easily, but I don't know your architecture, and your messages are hard to read.

Comment: I can't look currently, but whilst I had no issues with the i386 box (prior comment), the amd64 was different and you've confirmed your box is amd64 too. My intention is to return here later when I have time to explore your new detail on an amd64 box & re-learn floppies..

Comment: Another thing to check; I said the *amd64* I tested was different; turns out I'd disabled the floppy via a BIOS setting. Turns out I'd disabled the floppy in BIOS hence why it was different, thus check your BIOS settings.  Once i enabled floppy in bios, I could `mount` using right-click on `pcmanfm` (Lubuntu's lightweight file manager). Sorry I couldn't get to this earlier  *I'll return & re-read it again later*

Comment: You've mentioned the light on all the time; I would worry your drive is faulty with that piece of info, as I'm only used to seeing a drive led lit when in use (125ms or 250ms after use; 500ms for older [5.25"] drives).  I've already stated I can mount via Lubuntu's default `pcmanfm`, but from command I only used `sudo mount /dev/fd0 /mnt` (I used /mnt because I knew nothing was using it & knew it existed). The files can then be viewed via `ls /mnt`.  I made no changes to any system file, it worked automatically on i386 box, amd64 box needed me to enable floppy drive in bios only.

Comment: Please don't add detail via comment, it's hard to read & thus easy to miss information and mistakes become more likely. Are you sure the [3.5"] floppy contains valid data? and hasn't been left near speaker/anything-electrical and thus been wiped?  I'll try and experiment with different floppies and see if I can find a bad one to see what I get when floppy contains no or invalid data (mine are stored >2m from anything  electrical/magnetic) as I think it's that message, but you also get that for a mis-configured setup too I think (*you don't mention pcmanfm in your question, only nautilus*)

Comment: Finally found a bad 3.5" floppy. I get the error "**Error mounting /dev/fd0 at /media/guiverc/disk:/dev/fd0 is not a valid block device**" for invalid media.  (I also had `watch -d -n 1 'dmesg | tail -n 12'` showing in a window, the errors can easily seen there as it attempted to read detail from old floppy)

Comment: $USER for me is 'guiverc', so I don't understand why you'd use my username in a command (and can't see where you'd take that from my comments; though they can be harder to read). You are getting a different error to that I had for a bad floppy (no "**Error mounting** message); your result is closer to what I got before I enabled floppy in BIOS (which I'd also expect with a bad drive; ie. your drive light & prior comment).

Comment: @guiverc  Sorry to irritate you. I did not notice that your name was in the command. I am ignorant about commands, all I can do is to copy them and use them. I don't try to understand them. So I don't know how the command should look like without your name. Also, I don't understand your last bit: " ie. your drive light & prior comment"--- I tried many floppies, most of them were stacked next to an ink printer for years.

Comment: You're not irritating me, if you enter `echo $USER` at a CLI you'll see your username, that's written, the bold is only to highlight.. I suspect you have a bad drive (led light comment earlier) and I'd try on a different box, or replace the drive & try again (you may not have access to any..). I would also boot a 'live' system (eg. lubuntu 18.04 install media) and try there (ie. an unaltered config as you indicate making changes, I have none). Your drive maybe misbehaving as the PSU is struggling to provide amperage required (maybe needs check) but I'm suspicious of your hardware.

Comment: I doubt I'll be able to comment anymore, my Ubuntu sign-on (SSO) doesn't allow chat (that requires a StackExchange login)  but you could also try https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ (Lubuntu's forum, or Ubuntu Forum [https://ubuntuforums.org/]), but not many people still have fdd's on their boxes; even test boxes. I've not provided any copy/paste commands; only commands that I use and on occasion why I chose an option (expecting you to adjust for your box). I also haven't used my username in any command (it appeared in an error message, and output from an echo command, and as my site username only)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for all your comments. I did `echo $USER`  and confirmed my username. No surprise there. --- Let's assume the drive is faulty. We are under lockdown here, forced to stay at home. When it is over, I'll take my computer with the drive to a shop where they can check it and replace it if necessary. And they'll check my disks. Until then, I'll suspend my question. Thanks again and I am pleased that you are not irritated.

Comment: Did you try the 'live' environment?, ie. install media and just using the try/start option?  That uses a default setup. eg. I just booted a Lubuntu *focal fossa* (20.04) beta image on a box, opened `pcmanfm-qt` (the file manager) and clicked on the floppy icon in the Devices tab to the left, i hear to drive start up and see my word perfect files from 1994. The reason for 'live' is it'll prove your drive as it won't be impacted by any changes you've made to the system (I used the *focal fossa* as example only; it was handy and I knew that thumb-drive had a lubuntu on it)

Comment: @guiverc I'll try that, thank you! But not right now, I must finish something. It might be a while. Thanks again! And I'll try  `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/fd0 /media/vavruch` as well.

Comment: @vitalio I'll try it, thank you very much! Right now I am very busy and I have disconnected the drive because the light was on permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/fd0 /media/vavruch`

Comment: :D Seems like original question was "Anything else I could try?"